# Arduino question on Stack Overflow or Arduino Beta

Tags: discussion

Somehow I only recently realised there is a Arduino Stack Exchange site. In the past I would consider asking Arduino software questions on SO and anything that related to hardware issues (including software depending on/manipulating hardware) on Electronics Stack Exchange.

Should all Arduino questions (that can't be considered a purely system independent HW/SW question) be directed to Arduino SE in future?

Comment: Nobody can force users to pick a particular site.  Only 1 in 3 questions in the [arduino] tag get an answer so SO isn't exactly the ideal site.  If the Arduino site looks good to you then it would be a mistake to not take advantage of it.