# Arduino Site vs Arduino Tag

Tags: discussion, tags

This isn't a duplicate of [Arduino question on Stack Overflow or Arduino Beta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312412/arduino-question-on-stack-overflow-or-arduino-beta). I want to know why, not where I should post.

---

I have noticed that there is an [Arduino Stack Exchange site](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/) and an [arduino](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arduino) tag on Stack Overflow. Why don't we just move all of the questions from the tag onto the actual site, since [only 1 in 3 questions in the [arduino] tag get an answer so SO isn't exactly the ideal site](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312412/arduino-question-on-stack-overflow-or-arduino-beta#comment283222_312412)?

#### Statistics

Arduino site: 2,533 (unanswered questions) / 11,096 (all questions) is about 23% unanswered.
Arduino tag: 4,964 (unanswered questions) /10,739 (all questions) is about
46% unanswered.

46% of 11,096 = 5,104. 5,104 - 2,533 = 2,571. **More than double the questions could have/will be answered!**

Comment: In general there is no mass migrations of questions from SO... Could you please come up with a list of benefits that such migration would provide for this particular case? (short of making small dent in number of unanswered questions on SO)

Comment: Please be aware that the Arduino site is still in its beta phase.

Comment: Moving questions en masse to a beta site would be foolish. Also as a general rule we don't do this if the questions could be on topic on both sites.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov A small dent? See my edit. About 2,500 more questions would have been/will be answered.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Would you rather have 2 books each 500 pages with all the info you need on it, or have 1 book with 1,000 page with all your info in one place?

Comment: @honk Yup, that makes it sadder that almost double the amount of questions are answerered vs stackoverflow

Comment: @NoahCristino ["3,937,248
questions with no upvoted or accepted answers"](http://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/) - In my book 2500 of 4M is small dent at best...

Comment: BTW, I think you get your math wrong - adding 5K unanaswered questions to new site will lower "answered/all" ratio and will not magically get those questions answered...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Yeah, but if you can make even a little impact why not do it?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I know but still since a higher percentage of questions are answered it could help get some unanswered questions answered

Answer (score 5):

This is not a good idea for several reasons.

For one, the beta site may not survive.

And even if it does, *it may end up not wanting all those questions*.

Sometimes, specialist sites focusing on one topic will have a different expectation of quality than SO does. (Server Fault is a good example for that.)

Usually with topics that are on topic on both SO and the specialist site - and there are *loads* of those - a separation of what is best asked where evolves naturally, based on the culture that evolves on the specialist site.

Now, carefully migrating questions once a community culture has evolved may not be out of the question (although I'm not up to date on what the current policies on that are; it's definitely something that only moderators can do.)

But just dumping 10,000+ questions on a fledgling site is definitely not helpful to that evolution.

Comment: Good point. I'm going to edit, since people are interpreting my question as wanting to merge everything all at once. I just want to slowly transfer over the relevant questions that fit with the site, since if they dumped them all at once, tons would be forgotten and unanswered. If they were slowly transitioned over, it would almost "bump" the forgotten questions, and they would be answered. Plus, if only the answered questions from the tag were merged, it would just add more content to the site, and it would be easier to find, since most people would look for the site rather than, for the tag.